# multiple previews of the same equation

Tags: latex, auctex, previewing

I'm using auctex with texlab as a language server for latex, the problem i have is that i get multiple previews of the same equation [image: preview]

my question is how to get only one preview?

Comment: @Tyler - I think this has nothing to do with Org mode. The OP is using `auctex` and `preview`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I misspoke. I meant a minimal tex file

Comment: This isn't normal, you should get only one preview of each equation without any configuration. Can you provide a minimal tex file that gives you this problem? Preferably something short enough that you can edit it into your question.